# New Button on Account overriden with Lightning Component

Tags: apex, lightning-aura-components, lightning, security, button-overrides

I have overriden 'New' button on Account with an aura component. So when a user clicks on New button , all the Account record types get populated.
The issue is, user has access to only 2 record types out of 6 record types, but still he can see all record types and can select  either of the record type as soon as he clicks on New button.
I have checked profile as well as permission sets for the user and user has only access to two record types.

Expectation:
User should be able to see only two record types not all 6 record types.

```
 public with sharing class AccountSearchController {
 @AuraEnabled        
public static List<String> fetchRecordTypeValues(){
    List<Schema.RecordTypeInfo> recordtypes = Account.SObjectType.getDescribe().getRecordTypeInfos();    
    recordtypemap = new Map<Id, String>();
    for(RecordTypeInfo rt : recordtypes){
        if(rt.getName() != 'Master')
        recordtypemap.put(rt.getRecordTypeId(), rt.getName());
    }        
    return recordtypemap.values();
}

//Method to fetch recordtype ID 
@AuraEnabled
public static Id getRecTypeId(String recordTypeLabel){
    Id recid = Schema.SObjectType.Account.getRecordTypeInfosByName().get(recordTypeLabel).getRecordTypeId();        
    return recid;
}
```

}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess you need to check in apex class

Here is the code of apex where i check the record type of particular user

```
List<String> recordTypeNameList = new List<String>();
/** Need to create list to collect record type name.**/
Schema.DescribeSObjectResult R = Account.SObjectType.getDescribe();
/** You need to change the object name according to your requirement.**/
List<Schema.RecordTypeInfo> RT = R.getRecordTypeInfos();
for( Schema.RecordTypeInfo recordType : RT )
{
if(recordType.isAvailable())
 { 
 /** Check if the recordtype is visible for the current user or not. **/
if(recordType.Name!='Master') {
recordTypeNameSet.add(recordType.Name);
 /** Collect the record type name in list. **/
    }
  }
}
```

Then after then i will call this apex method in aura and work accordingly .

Comment: I have written the apex class in same way.
Further i am adding the apex class in the question

Comment: Try this maybe this will help you , https://ipfs-sec.stackexchange.cloudflare-ipfs.com/salesforce/A/question/5063.html

Comment: Thanks @Sahil Malhotra.
After i put an extra check inside the for loop as below, it worked.
if(recordType.isAvailable()){ }